# Terminal asking for input twice

Tags: python

I am trying to make a word guessing program in Python since I am new to programming. I made it so that the terminal asks you for your guess, but when you respond, it asks you a second time. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I tried using variables instead of functions, and I tried looking up solution, but I just can’t find any.

```
import random

def guess():
    x = input("What's your guess? ")
    return x

def anslet():
    q = answer[0]
    return q

def glet():
    w = guess()[0]
    return w

answers = ["mouse", "sound", "apple"]
answer = random.choice(answers)
print(answer)

while guess() != answer:
    if glet() == anslet():
        print("good")

print("Correct!")
```

Comment: @JohnGordon Didn't see that `answers` and `answer` were different. My mistake.

Comment: This carefully about the logic of the code. Where it says `w = guess()[0]`, what does this mean, step by step? When you run the program, how many total times do you expect the `guess` function to be called? Why? Every time that `guess` is called, `input` gets called, right? Do you see how this explains the observed result? Before asking future questions, please read [ask] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and carefully check what the code does, step by step. Stack Overflow does not exist to find bugs, but to explain them.

Answer (score 1):

```
while guess() != answer:
    if glet() == anslet():
        print("good")
```

`guess()` asks the user for input.

`glet()` calls `guess()`.

So, `guess()` is called once in the first `if` condition, and again in the second `if` condition...

Answer (score -1):

Your program calls for the function "guess()" in the while's condition (first input), and afterwards it calls for the function "glet()" (that calls the function "guess()") in the if's condition (second input).

```
def guess():
    x = input("What's your guess? ") # here is the input of the function "guess()"
    return x

...

def glet():
w = guess()[0] # and here the function "glet" calls for the function "guess()"
return w


...

while guess() != answer:   # first input
    if glet() == anslet(): # second input
        print("good")

print("Correct!")
```